# Invariant Violation react native while running from a different machine

Tags: android, react-native

Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

I have a project with the nativave version 0.57.5 and react 16.6.3 and am running it in windows. There is no probleam with this on my system at office but when i tried the same project on my office laptop am not able to run.Actually it is completed with the build but after 2 screens I am getting the invariant violation message, still its wrking fine in the desktop. is there any issue with the java version? please help. I am stuck and not able to identify what is the problem,

Answer (score 2):

Check your exports. It is related to exporting the component. You likely forgot copying a js file, or naming mismatches. Check all the components used in your screen where this error shows up. One of them must be causing the issue.